# Determine which transaction spent a Transaction Output

Tags: utxo

I will explain my question through an example on the bitcoin testnet network.

I am looking at the output at index 0 of this transaction:

```
2a50bcc2ec49573ef816a95781b802766910f8690968236cf451cfc32defc491
```

I can tell through the bitcoin testnet block explorer that it was spent [in this transaction](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/tx/7b1b3788ae4251d164031f899ba4e81f6371f70c24e71d38b03d44292ada9c81#i74294159):

```
7b1b3788ae4251d164031f899ba4e81f6371f70c24e71d38b03d44292ada9c81
```

Is there a way to use the bitcoind RPC methods to determine that it was 7b1b3... that was the transaction that spent this transaction output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoind does not track this information as it is not necessary for normal validation, so no, this is not easily possible.

Comment: What I suspected. Any plans to do that?